# Order is not geting created, but transition is happening in cart

Tags: commerce, 9

I am doing an `Offsite redirection` payment with Drupal Commerce.
I have a custom payment workflow defined in `my_module.workflow.yml` as follows:

```
order_linktypeplus_validation:
  id: order_linktypeplus_validation
  group: commerce_order
  label: 'linktypeplus order workflow'
  states:
    draft:
      label: Draft
    pending:
      label: Pending
    completed:
      label: Completed
    canceled:
      label: Canceled
  transitions:
    place:
      label: 'Place order'
      from: [draft]
      to: pending
    fulfill:
      label: 'Fulfill order'
      from: [draft, pending]
      to: completed
    cancel:
      label: 'Cancel order'
      from: [draft, pending]
      to: canceled
```

So as per this when the order is placed, First order will be moved to the `Pending` state (which is working fine). And for some orders, I need to get it completed without the pending state (ie. from draft to completed)

I was doing this in my controller after offsite payment had been successfully done and returned to the site:

```
 $order->unlock();
 $order->setData($paymentGateway, $data);
 if ($order->getState()->getId() != 'completed') {
      $order->getState()->applyTransitionById('fulfill');
  }
 $order->save();
```

When I checked in the cart tab next to orders, the item was still in the cart. but its status says `Order moved from Draft to Completed by the Fulfill order transition`. But the **order is not created**. [image]

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> But the order is not created.

What do you mean by that? The order in your screenshot has the completed state?

Comment: The screenshot is of the `Cart` tab. The order tab is not showing this. The `Completed` state is showing is for payments(i guess)